# scaffold 後、http://localhost:3000/ideasでエラー　ExecJS::ProgramError in Ideas#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails

rails g scaffold 後、http://localhost:3000/ideas でエラーがでます。　
ExecJS::ProgramError in Ideas#index 
(TypeError: オブジェクトでサポートされていないプロパティまたはメソッドです。)

(インストールした gem coffee-script-sourceを削除しようとしているうち)  現在、ブラウザとターミナルに、以前と同じ下記のエラーがでるようになりました。　
(現在、>gem listで coffee-script-source (1.12.2, 1.8.0) が表示されます)　　
宜しくお願いします。

[ブラウザ]

```
ExecJS::ProgramError in Ideas#index
Showing C:/Users/○○○/planbook/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #7 raised:

TypeError: オブジェクトでサポートされていないプロパティまたはメソッドです。
Extracted source (around line #7):

5    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
6
7    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
8    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
9  </head>


Rails.root: C:/Users/○○○/planbook

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__926657132_127000760'
Request
Parameters:
```

[ターミナル]

```
Started GET "/ideas" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-04-13 09:48:37 +0900
Processing by IdeasController#index as HTML
Rendering ideas/index.html.erb within layouts/application
Idea Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "ideas".* FROM "ideas"
Rendered ideas/index.html.erb within layouts/application (15.6ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1069ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


ActionView::Template::Error (TypeError: オブジェクトでサポートされていないプロパティまたはメソッドです。):
4:     <title>Planbook</title>
5:     <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
6:
7:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
8:     <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
9:   </head>

app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__270033951_105504200'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gem coffee-script-source 1.8.0 以外はエラーになるとのことがわかり解決しました。